# Rendering light bloom with transparency

Tags: transparency, lighting

I'm using Eevee (on a Mac). I'm (fairly?) well-versed in the theory behind my question, but less so with Blender itself.

Basically: I'm trying to render out a scene in separate elements for compositing elsewhere. I have a light source with bloom on one element, and when I render it with (Film) transparency on, I get this:

[image]

(comped onto a black background) when what I really want is this:

[image]

(rendered onto a black background). Obviously in the former it's clipping to the non-transparent image edge.

Is there a way to control premultiplication options of alpha for light bloom (if indeed I'm correctly interpreting what's happening)?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: make sure you're rendering to OpenEXR, like I wasn't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)